# Error en php y sql por medio de conexion odbc

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Tengo el siguiente código. Al momento que ejecuto en el navegador me indica el único error:

> odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\AppServ\www\centrales\index.php on line 64

la linea 64 es la siguiente:

```
$result = odbc_exec($sql,$cid);
```

codigo php

```
<?php include("templates/header.php"); ?>
<h1>Centrales vs Mediacion</h1>
<h3>Listado de Centrales</h3>
<div id="filtros">
Selecciona la central <form action="index.php" method="post"><select name="filtro"><option value="todos"></option><option value="Nimajuyu">Nimajuyu</option><option value="El Carmen 2">El Carmen 2</option><option value="Monte Verde 5">Monte Verde 5</option><option value="Lourdes EIN">Lourdes EIN</option><option value="Guarda Transito">Guarda Transito</option><option value="Guarda Viejo 5">Guarda Viejo 5</option><option value="Centro Transito EIN">Centro Transito EIN</option><option value="Tivoli">Tivoli</option><option value="Villa de Guadalupe 3">Villa de Guadalupe 3</option><option value="Aristos">Aristos</option><option value="Chimaltenango">Chimaltenango</option><option value="Retalhuleu">Retalhuleu</option><option value="Zacapa">Zacapa</option></select> <button type="submit">Filtrar</button></form>
</div>
<div id="productos">
    <?php
        $result = odbc_exec($sql,$cid);
        echo '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th width="150">central</th>
                <th width="150">centrales_nombre</th>
                <th width="150">fecha_dcms</th>
                <th width="150">archivo_dcms</th>
                <th width="150">correlativo_dcms</th>
                <th width="150">bytes_dcms</th>
                <th width="150">archivo_ivr</th>
                <th width="150">correlativo_ivr</th>
                <th width="150">fecha_ivr</th>
                <th width="150">bytes_ivr</th>
                <th width="150">ivr_num_eventos</th>
                <th width="150">dif_bytes</th>      
            </tr>';
if(($registro)>0)
{
    while($registro2 = odbc_fetch_array($registro)){ 
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$registro2['central'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['centrales_nombre'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['fecha_dcms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['archivo_dcms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['correlativo_dcms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['bytes_dcms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['archivo_ivr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['correlativo_ivr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['fecha_ivr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['bytes_ivr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['ivr_num_eventos'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['dif_bytes'].'</td>
                </tr>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<tr>
                <td colspan="6">No se encontraron resultados</td>
            </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

Donde las variables han sido definidas previamente asi

```
$sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (208) order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
```

Comment: En donde defines las variables $sql y $cid?

Comment: La defino por medio de una query es la siguiente:$sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (208) order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tienes los parametros al revez.  Primero va la conexion y despues el query asi:

```
$result = odbc_exec($cid, $sql);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alanfcm ahora solucione el error, te lo agradezco ya funciona, perdon pero soy nuevo aun en la programacion.  saludos.

Comment: De nada, por cierto, yo tambien soy Chapin

Comment: Ohh genial me llegas primo!!! buena honda.